# chatterbot só entrega um caracter como resposta

Tags: python, python-3.x, chatbot

Estou estudando sobre o chatterbot e no primeiro teste de treino apareceu que ele só me entregou os primeiros caracteres como resposta, alguem sabe me explicar pq?

```
from chatterbot import ChatBot
from chatterbot.trainers import ListTrainer
import os

bot = ChatBot('teste')
treino = ListTrainer(bot)

diretorio = '/Users/archo/PycharmProjects/untield/venv/testechatbot/treinadores/'
for treinadores in os.listdir(diretorio):
    treino.train(diretorio + treinadores)

while True:
    req = str(input("Voce: "))
    req = bot.get_response(req)
    print('Bot: ' + str(req))
```

[nltk_data] Downloading package averaged_perceptron_tagger to

[nltk_data]     /Users/archo/nltk_data...

[nltk_data]   Package averaged_perceptron_tagger is already up-to-

[nltk_data]       date!

[nltk_data] Downloading package stopwords to /Users/archo/nltk_data...

[nltk_data]   Package stopwords is already up-to-date!

List Trainer: [####################] 100%

List Trainer: [####################] 100%

List Trainer: [####################] 100%

List Trainer: [####################] 100%

Voce: oi

Bot: t

Voce: bom dia

Bot: o

**eu fiz um subdiretorio chamado treinadores com arquivos .yml para treinar ele**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontrei o erro, eram os arquivos em YAML que por algum motivo não estavam sendo lidos, nem os do chatterbot-corpus. Refiz em json os arquivos de treino e funcionaram

```
import json

from chatterbot import ChatBot
from chatterbot.trainers import ListTrainer

with open('treino.json') as f:
    words = json.load(f)
bot = ChatBot('teste', read_only=True)
treinador = ListTrainer(bot)
teste = words["conversations"]
treinador.train(teste)
```